# Running an OpenCL kernel on multiple GPUs

Tags: opencl

I have an OpenCL kernel and I want to run it on all detected OpenCL capable devices (like all available GPUs) on different systems, I'd be thankful to know if there is any straightforward method. I mean like creating a single command queue for all devices.

Thanks in advance :]

Comment: Create separate contexts for each device and run then in separate threads (e.g. with pthreads).

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a single command queue for all devices; a given command queue is tied to a single device. However, you can create separate command queues for each OpenCL device and feed them work, which should execute concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

As Dithermaster points out you first create a separate command queue for each device, for instance you might have multiple GPUs.  You can then place these in an array, e.g., here is a pointer to an array that you can setup:

```
cl_command_queue* commandQueues;
```

However in my experience it has not always been a "slam-dunk" in getting the various command queues executing concurrently, as can be verified using event timing information (checking for overlap) which you can get through your own profiling or using 3rd party profiling tools. You should do this step anyway to verify what does or does not work on your setup.

An alternative approach which can work quite nicely is to use OpenMP to execute the command queues concurrently, e.g., you do something like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared)
    for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; ++i) {
            someOpenCLFunction(commandQueues[i], ....);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have N devices, and a 100 elements of work (jobs). What you should do is something like this:

```
#define SIZE 3

std::vector<cl::Commandqueue> queues(SIZE); //One queue for each device (same context)
std::vector<cl::Kernel> kernels(SIZE); //One kernel for each device (same context)
std::vector<cl::Buffer> buf_in(SIZE), buf_out(SIZE); //One buffer set for each device (same context)

// Initialize the queues, kernels, buffers etc....
//Create the kernel, buffers and queues, then set the kernel[0] args to point to buf_in[0] and buf_out[0], and so on...

// Create the events in a finished state
std::vector<cl::Event> events;
cl::UserEvent ev; ev.setStatus(CL_COMPLETE);
for(int i=0; i<queues.size(); i++)
    events.push_back(ev);

//Run all the elements (a "first empty, first run" scheduler)
for(int i=0; i<jobs.size(); i++){
    bool found = false;
    int x = -1;
    //Try all the queues
    while(!found){
        for(int j=0; j<queue.size(); j++)
            if(events[j].getInfo<CL_EVENT_COMMAND_ EXECUTION_STATUS>() == CL_COMPLETED){
                found = true;
                x = j;
                break;
            }
        if(!found) Sleep(50); //Sleep a while if not all the queues have completed, other options are possible (like asigning the job to a random one)
    }
    //Run it
    events[x] = cl::Event(); //Clean it
    queues[x].enqueueWriteBuffer(...); //Copy buf_in
    queues[x].enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel[x], .... ); //Launch the kernel
    queues[x].enqueueReadBuffer(... , events[x]); //Read buf_out
}

//Wait for completion
for(int i=0; i<queues.size(); i++)
    queue[i].Finish();
```

Comment: What if muliple devices needed to run same kernel? Will the buffers implicitly be shared between devices(copied implicitly) so do I need different contexts for different devices altogether? Or there are no implicit copies and a buffer has instances in all devices and altered independently?

Comment: I am supposing same context for all the application, that means the buffers are automatically copied between devices when needed. You need one kernel+queue+buffers for each pipeline(device).

Comment: so if i need same sorting algorithm, i need to compile for each device? Thank you.

Comment: The build process is common, just build for all the devices at the same time.